# Mutate value based on first row above that satisfies a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data, a simplified version of which looks like this:

```
 df_current <- data.frame(
  start = c('yes', rep('no', 5), 'yes', rep('no', 3)),
  season = c('banana', rep('to update', 5), 'apple', rep('to update', 3)),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Let's say that the "start" variable indicates when a new season starts, and I can use that in combination with a date variable (not included) to indicate where apple and banana season start. Once this is done, I want to update the rest of the rows in the "season" column. All of the rows which currently have the value "to update" should be updated to have the value of the type of fruit whose season has most recently started (the rows are arranged by date). In other words, I want the data to look like this:

```
 df_desired <- data.frame(
  start = c('yes', rep('no', 5), 'yes', rep('no', 3)),
  season = c(rep('banana', 6), rep('apple', 4)),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

I had assumed that something like the following would work:

```
  updated <- df_current %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(season = case_when(
    season != 'to update' ~ season,
    season == 'to update' ~ lag(season)
  ))
```

However, that generates NAs at all the 'to update' values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to `replace` `"to update"` with `NA` and then use `fill`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_current %>%
  mutate(season = replace(season, season == "to update", NA)) %>%
  fill(season)

#   start season
#1    yes banana
#2     no banana
#3     no banana
#4     no banana
#5     no banana
#6     no banana
#7    yes  apple
#8     no  apple
#9     no  apple
#10    no  apple
```

Using the same logic you can also use `zoo::na.locf` to fill missing values with latest non-missing values.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you generate a bunch of `NA`s is due to `season` containing only a single value in each `case_when` evaluation, and thus `lag(season)` always producing `NA`. Here is another base R solution that uses `rle`:

```r
x <- rle(df_current$season)
x
#> Run Length Encoding
#>   lengths: int [1:4] 1 5 1 3
#>   values : chr [1:4] "banana" "to update" "apple" "to update"

x$values[x$values == "to update"] <- x$values[which(x$values == "to update") - 1]
x
#> Run Length Encoding
#>   lengths: int [1:4] 1 5 1 3
#>   values : chr [1:4] "banana" "banana" "apple" "apple"

df_current$season <- inverse.rle(x)

df_current
#>    start season
#> 1    yes banana
#> 2     no banana
#> 3     no banana
#> 4     no banana
#> 5     no banana
#> 6     no banana
#> 7    yes  apple
#> 8     no  apple
#> 9     no  apple
#> 10    no  apple
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You mention that there is only a single value in each case_when() evaluation - I assume this is because of the call to rowwise() rather than case_when() itself?

Comment: @userLL: yes indeed, without `rowwise` you still run into issues, as `lag(season)` does not get recalculated in an iterative fashion after each update in the `season` column

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na_if`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_current %>%
    mutate(season = na_if(season, "to update")) %>%
    fill(season)
#   start season
#1    yes banana
#2     no banana
#3     no banana
#4     no banana
#5     no banana
#6     no banana
#7    yes  apple
#8     no  apple
#9     no  apple
#10    no  apple
```